# Searching for binary range coincidence over many dimensions

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis

I've clarified and simplified the question:

I have data that looks like this:

```
011100111110100111
111111111111110010
111100001111000011
```

1D lanes of streams of data.  Each row signifies the presence of a type with a 1 or a 0.  Types tend to exist in chunks across the stream.  The vertical order of the rows doesn't matter.

I am seeking patterns where dimensions coincide at two or more indices, both at the **start of '1' group's**, and also **where any '1' groups overlap** across all rows/dimensions.

Pattern can be offset with nearby adjacent indices, if it's proportion is maintained.

D = Dimension/Row
N = Index in stream

(( D1(N), D25(N+4), D900(N-1) ), ( 3, 67, 90, 3000 ))

An example of a pattern match that migh occur at multiple places.  Dimension01 at N, Dimension25 at index N + 4, Dimension900 at index N -1 occur at indices 3, 67, 90 and 3000.

#### The returned patterns:

- Are ordered by the number of matching indices or by the number of dimensions in the pattern.
- Match at least two dimensions at at least two points

How can I go about this?

Comment: hmm, this question is unclear to me. I read it as I have some difficult unordered binary data ... Try to specify what data you have (how did you get it), what is final goal, what did you try, why it failed ... It should be much clearer

Comment: Hi, xhudik. I just edited my post to clarify the question.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "dimension". Is the order of the columns relevant? If each column corresponds to a "dimension" then for instance swapping column number 2 with say column 18 does not modify the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, appraoches for [Frequent Itemset Mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) might be what you are looking for. As a starting point I would look into the famous [Apriori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) algorithm, which is one of the most basic techniques to detect common blocks of "1" elements in your example (assuming that we can interpret each column as an independent dimension, and there is no specific semantic/relationship between the dimension, which would modify the problem since the order of dimensions becomes meaningful).